# Undefined References to SDL_mixer functions from a static library (Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, static-libraries, codeblocks, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

So, I've made a static library with references to SDL_mixer functions (and those work fine), but when I try to build the project that links to the library, Code::Blocks tells me that every function used (in the static library) is an undefined reference. I've searched and searched, but everyone else seems to always have a linker problem, so here is my order: -lSDL2,
-lSDL2_ttf,
-lSDL2_mixer,
-lGL,
-lGLEW, and then my library

Everything works fine, except for the one file that I try to use SDL_mixer functions. And by the way, everything worked before I converted to Code::Blocks. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is exact linking line and error message?

Comment: Dont add those `[SOLVED]` labels to the title. Instead, write an answer yourself and mark it as accepted. This is how the site is intended to work.

Comment: Sorry about the label. I'm new to the site. I'll write an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the order that I was linking the libraries. I changed the order so that my library was linked before the rest, and it worked perfectly

I guess I shouldn't be so confident with my own code so much :|